# How do we express that you are riding a motorbike / a bike / a horse with your friend sitting behind you on it?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Look at the verb "[**ride**](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/ride_1?q=ride)" in the dictionary

> [transitive, intransitive] to sit on and control a bicycle,
>   motorcycle, etc.
>
> **ride something + adv./prep.** The boys were riding their bikes
>   around the streets.
>
> **ride something** He rode a Harley Davidson.
>
> It 's like riding a bicycle: one day you can't and the next day you
>   can.
>
> **+ adv./prep.** The ground there is too rough to ride over.

---

and the verb "**[drive](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/drive_1?q=drive)**"

> [transitive] to take somebody somewhere in a car, taxi, etc.
>
> **drive somebody + adv./prep.** Could you drive me home?
>
> My mother drove us to the airport.
>
> They were driven to an unknown place in the hills.
>
> **drive somebody** I don't want to take the bus. Will you drive me?

---

We normally say "**to ride a motorbike / a bike / a Harley / a horse  etc**" or "**to ride on a motorbike / a bike / a Harley / a horse etc**"

But I am not sure if we can say "**to ride a person on a motorbike / a bike / a Harley / a horse etc**"

For example, can we say "**I am riding my friend on my motorbike / bike / horse**"?

However, the verb "**drive**" can be followed by a person, for example, we can say "**I drove her to the airport in my car**". But "**drive**" is often used with a truck, a car, a taxi. I am not sure if it can be used with a motorbike, a bike, a horse, etc.

For example, can we say "**I drove her to the airport on my motorbike / bike / horse**"?

**How do we express that you are riding a motorbike / bike / horse with your friend sitting behind you on it?**

Comment: Horses are not driven, unless they are pulling a carriage, they are ridden. Besides, they are not a common form of public transportation,  so it probably deserves a separate question of its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "[Pillion](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pillion) passenger" is a person sitting behind the driver on a motorbike.

You don't say "I rode a pillion passenger". It is possible to say

> I took a pillion passenger
>   I carried my friend as a pillion passenger
>   I rode with my friend as a pillion passenger

You can use the phrase "ride pillion"

> My friend rode pillion.  (but avoid "I rode my friend pillion")

You sometimes see it as verb, though this is somewhat non-standard

> Learn to pillion   (but avoid "he pillioned")

Pillion is the right word for motorbikes, it would also be the right word for the back seat of a pedal bike (though I have never seen such a thing).  Technically it is also the word for a small cushion that can be used for a second rider on a horse, but now the word is only in common use for motorbikes. Double saddles are rare.

If the rider isn't on a separate seat then you could used "carry"

> George carried his son in a child seat on his bike.

Normally, though you would use the person being carried as the subject

> George's son rode in a child seat in front.
>   Mary rode behind Susan on their horse
>   Katie perched on the back axle of Mike's bike.

You can't use "ride" as a transitive verb, because the direct object of "ride" is the bike/horse

> He rode a horse (OK)
>   He rode Mary on a horse (not OK)

The verb "drive" is usually used with cars, and not motorbikes.

> I drove Mary to work (suggests "by car")

Comment: What if the passenger (like a small child, for example) sit in front of the rider? do we have a name for the seat before the rider on a motorbike?

Comment: Besides, "pillion"  is quite complicated, can we say "I drove her on my motorbike"?

Comment: In addition, "pillion" is not generic, it is a back seat of a motorcycle. What about a backseat of a bicycle, tricycle, horse, etc. We often see 2 people on a horse in movies. How do we express in that situation?

Comment: I've edited.  Not "drove" but "carried". But better to change the subject. Pillion is the precise word, for a precise meaning. "Pillion" is common enough that I'd understand it when applied to the (rare) situations of two horse riders.

Comment: but what about the person is sitting in front of the rider (like a little child, for example)?

Comment: Please read the answer. That would be "in a child seat" or "in my lap" (front child seats are rare, perhaps unknown in the UK)

Comment: But in some poor countries, they don't have a child seat, they just share the seat. The child, the dad & the mom all on the same seat of the motorbike.

Comment: Riding pillion on a horse was common enough in earlier centuries, especially for women who couldn't afford a carriage. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pillion

Comment: Ok, so pillion is common then & can be used for bikes, horses, etc

Comment: @KateBunting In fact the word 'pillion' meaning 'ride behind'  was in existence centuries before motorbikes existed. The 'pillion seat' on a motorbike came from riding pillion on horses. It's like 'dashboard' which was originally the part of a horse drawn vehicle that stopped mud 'dashing' onto the occupants' legs. For instance the dashboard of The Surrey With the Fringe On Top is 'genuine leather'.

Comment: @BoldBen Yes, I know - that was the point of my comment (in response to Tom's not knowing that the word could apply to horse riding).

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, I was agreeing with you, but I thought it was worth the expansion

Answer (score 1):

You might say, "I rode a horse with my friend sitting behind me." This sentence would indicate you were most probably the one in control.

Alternatively, "My friend and I rode a horse together, and I held the reins." This makes it clear who was in control.

Comment: is there a way to make it shorter. For example, "I rode my friend on a horse" (which broke the standard structure)?